# Overloading operator* ambigious with operator double()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

g++ can't compile this program because: 
"

```
45:20: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
xxx.cpp:27:15: note: candidate 1: const Point2d Point2d::operator*(float) const
 const Point2d Point2d::operator*(float xy) const
xxx.cpp:45:20: note: candidate 2: operator*(double, int) <built-in>
  Point2d x = xxx * 3;
```

"

When I delete "operator double()" then "operator *" works, but is there an option to have those to operators at once?

code:

```
class Point2d {
    public :
        Point2d(float x, float y);
        const Point2d operator*(float xy) const;
        operator double(); //when I delete operator double(), then operator* works
    private :
        float x;
        float y;
};

Point2d::operator double()
{
    return sqrt((this->x * this->x) + (this->y * this->y));
}


const Point2d Point2d::operator*(float xy) const
{
    return Point2d(x * xy, y * xy);
}


Point2d::Point2d(float x, float y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

int main()
{
    Point2d xxx(3, 5.5);
    Point2d x = xxx * 3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Overloading the `operator double()` to return the length of the vector is confusing, a method that return the length of it would be clearer, e.g. `float length() const { return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }`

Answer (score 1):

In `xxx * 3` the compiler can either convert `3` to `float` and use `operator*(float xy)` or convert `xxx` to `double` using `operator double()` and then use the built-in multiplication.

The rules say that this is ambiguous, so it is not allowed to choose either.

When you remove the conversion, one of the options goes away and so it is no longer ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, so I just have to do something like this: `Point2d x = xxx * (float)3 `and it works. Thank you so much :)